# Can you change button assignments on a bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth

I just bought a bluetooth headset (MPOW H18) for work, but something is weird.

It seems that the configuration that was applied to my headset takes the raise/lower volume buttons, but wrongly assigns them to next/previous media.

I would like to modify the configuration. To put the right configuration for the right button. I think usually you can do so for controllers (like the X button is A) but can you do it for a bluetooth headset?

EDIT: It's the MPOW H18. But what I'm asking is in general, can I change the button assignments of a bluetooth connected device.

Comment: For the one who voted as too broad... how could I make my question less broad?

Comment: You have to hold it for volume.

Comment: Which brand & model? Have you checked its manual? Many headset has driver /app, have you installed it?

Comment: @Fredy31, please find the model (on the same sticker as the serial number) and then click [edit] here; put the make and model number into your question. Please do not click Add Comment, instead use [edit].

Comment: "what I'm asking is in general, can I change the button assignments of a bluetooth connected device" - in general the answer is NO, there is no way changing button functions.